# how to move a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, move

XAML code is below

```
<Window x:Class="DenemeWpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Width="Auto"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Height="Auto"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   Grid.RowSpan="1">

            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkKhaki" Offset=".3" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkKhaki" Offset=".7" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Button Name="simpleButton"
                            Click="simpleButtonClick"
                            KeyDown="simpleButton_KeyDown">Simple</Button>
                    <Button Name="cubeButton"
                            Click="cubeButtonClick">Cube</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport"
                        ClipToBounds="True">
                <Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="100"
                                       LookDirection="-11,-10,-9"
                                       UpDirection="0,1,0"
                                       NearPlaneDistance="1"
                                       Position="11,10,9"
                                       FieldOfView="70" />
                </Viewport3D.Camera>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-2,-3,-1" />
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this is inide XAML.cs

```
private void simpleButton_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.P) {
        //something to move the simpleButton
    }
}
```

I want to move `simpleButton` when P is pressed from keyboard, but I can't seem to find any method or way to do that.

Comment: Where do you want to move it to? You would have to manually remove it from the StackPanel and add it to a new parent to actually move it. You could apply a RenderTransform to give the appearance that it moved.

Comment: Be more specific about what you want to do/happen.

Comment: @H.B. As I said I am very new so What if I don't have the information to be specific?

Comment: @CodeNaked Thanks Mr.Naked I will check RenderTransform.

Comment: I still do not understand why this question got 6 downvotes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if animation is not required just do

```
if (e.Key == Key.P)
{
   cubeButton.Margin = new Thickness(60, 50, 50, 60);
}
```

left,top,right,bottom should be numbers

and you have added `keydown` `event` to button so button must be focused in order to receive the `keydown` event

also look at [TranslateTransform in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/360/)

Comment: Thank you Lagrangian, I tried that before and it worked however I am looking for a more dynamic way for next steps.Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: dynamic ways ? please what you intend to have

Comment: Like using TranslateTransform thank you for your interest Lagrangian.

Comment: thank you very understandable example, I shall accept your answer after you edit your question with the code in the link.

Answer (score 3):

to move the button within the grid you have to handle the keydown event of the MainWindow, see following example:

```
       private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.P)
        {
            button1.Margin = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
        }
    }
```

Also if you have not explained how the focus on the active form KeyDown event will not be
recalled.

Bye

Answer (score 2):

You can move it many ways.  You could put it on a Canvas control and change its Canvas.Left or Canvas.Top.  You could put it inside a Grid and change its Grid.Row or Grid.Column.  Probably the most flexible way is to apply a TranslateTransform to it, which will also move it the amount you specify.

Comment: Thanks Mr.AresAvatar I think what I am looking for is TranslateTransform however I can't seem to find a good tutorial to learn about that, do you have any ideas or links?

Comment: This page has a nice example of a rectangle that, when clicked, slides 200 WPF pixels with a TranslateTransform animation: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx

Comment: Thank you I will check and try it.